# bash: pip: command not found

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-2.6

I downloaded pip and ran `python setup.py install` and everything worked just fine. The very next step in the tutorial is to run `pip install <lib you want>` but before it even tries to find anything online I get an error "bash: pip: command not found".

This is on Mac OS X. I'm assuming there's some kind of path setting that was not set correctly when I ran `setup.py`. How can I investigate further? What do I need to check to get a better idea of the exact cause of the problem?

**EDIT:** I also tried installing Python 2.7 for Mac in the hopes that the friendly install process would do any housekeeping like editing PATH and whatever else needs to happen for everything to work according to the tutorials, but this didn't work. After installing, running 'python' still ran Python 2.6 and PATH was not updated.

Comment: Did the installation of pip report it was successful?

Comment: Perhaps you need to run the command as root?

Comment: I am running terminal using sudo, so everything should be run as root. The installed did report success.

Comment: It's because the python3 path (\bin\) doesn't have "pip" anymore, it has "pip3". Open your terminal and type "pip3 -v" and I'm sure you'll see it's there. Ever since Python 3.5 pip has been included with Python but they renamed it slightly. Hope that helps.

Comment: pip 3 work for me. Ex: pip3 install APScheduler

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is almost ten years old and is specific to a completely obsolete version of Python. As asked, it can only serve to mislead newcomers - since if `pip` is missing from an up-to-date installation then most of the answers here are at best nonsensical and at worst actively harmful.

Comment: @SWalsh The question specifically mentions using Python 2.7, so a python3 solution doesn't help users who are using Python 2.7.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel how about editing the body instead with a warning label near the top if you believe so firmly? I don't know Python well myself.

Answer (score 567):

Why not just do `sudo easy_install pip` or if this is for python 2.6 `sudo easy_install-2.6 pip`?

This installs pip using the default python package installer system and saves you the hassle of manual set-up all at the same time.

This will allow you to then run the `pip` command for python package installation as it will be installed with the system python. I also recommend once you have pip using the [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package and pattern. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorry but I'm a newbie `sudo: easy_install: command not found`

Comment: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (python 3.4)

Comment: The link that @PaigeLo posted seems to lead to a random page that made my Safari freeze...would not recommend doing that

Comment: sudo apt install python-pip?

Comment: This assumes you have `easy_install` installed. How is this an answer?

Comment: Easy Install is deprecated. Do not use it. Instead use pip. - https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Comment: How do you use pip to install pip?

Answer (score 495):

**2020 Update**:

For current Debian/Ubuntu, use

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

to install `pip3`.

---

*Old 2013 answer* (easy_install is now deprecated):

<strike>Use setuptools to install pip:</strike> `sudo easy_install pip`

<strike>(I know the above part of my answer is redundant with klobucar's, but I can't add comments yet), so here's an answer with a solution to `sudo: easy_install: command not found` on Debian/Ubuntu:</strike> `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

<strike>Also, for python3, use `easy_install3` and `python3-setuptools`.</strike>

For Python 3, use `apt-get install python3-pip`.

Comment: for pip3:
`sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools` &
`sudo easy_install3 pip`

Comment: this is the right answer `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` followed by `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: @Smily But the question states explicitly that this is for macOS, not Ubuntu

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati you are right and [this answer seems more related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340173/9714920](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340173/9714920)

Comment: after installing pytho3-setuptools, i have a command not found trying to execute easy_install3

Answer (score 373):

First of all: try **pip3** instead of **pip**. Example:

```
pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

pip3 should be installed automatically together with Python3.x. The documentation hasn't been updated, so simply replace *pip* by *pip3* in the instructions, when installing Flask for example.

Now, if this doesn't work, you might have to install pip separately.

Comment: All those who installed ubuntu 16 should try this first.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS after `brew install python`.

Comment: That was exactly my case. Installed Python from .pkg file.

Comment: And you can use pip2 if you are using Python 2.x

Answer (score 67):

**Update**: A more reliable modern way to access the right pip install for the right python install is to use the syntax `python -m pip`.

**Original Answer**

pip would install itself into the bin of your python installation location. It also should create a symlink to some more common location like `/usr/local/bin/pip`

You can either edit your `~/.profile` and update your PATH to include `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin`, or you could create a symlink to it in a place that you know is in your path.

If you do:  `echo $PATH`, you should see the paths currently being searched. If `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH, you can do:

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip /usr/local/bin
```

I would opt for adding the python bin to your $PATH variable.

Comment: Also, there is no /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/ - only 2.7, and the only appeared after I ran the Python 2.7 installer moments ago. Does this mean the default Python 2.6 that comes with Mac doesn't conform to whatever ever standard file locations you assumed?

Comment: The system version may be here `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin`. And ~/ is your home directory with the hidden file `.profile`

Comment: There is no file .profile in ~/ but there is a .bash_profile. Are they the same?

Comment: macos: ln -s ~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @Kesha Antonov that would only work if one actually installed Python into their own user home directory. And then, symlinking it to the system /usr/local/bin would potentially break for other user accounts.

Comment: @jdi You suggested in your answer to do "ln". Isn't it safe?

Comment: @Kesha Antonov I didn't mean that using a symlink at all is bad. Yes my examples show symlinks but they are from system locations that are available to any user of the machine. My argument is that you suggested to link from a single user's home directory install of python into a system location. That means there could be the potential for breakage of another user of the system. While you may only have a system with one user, your suggestion won't always work for everyone.

Comment: @jdi Ahh... I got it. Thanks for the explanation! Yep, I think you're right.

Answer (score 55):

I encountered this problem having downloaded python 3.x.x and trying to install awscli - `pip: command not found`.

Whilst following the instructions for downloading the AWS client, I changed

```
pip install awscli
```

to

```
pip3 install awscli
```

which ran the correct version.

I've made an alias on my machine to run python3 whilst typing python, which would normally run the system version 2.7. I'm not sure this is a good idea now. I think I'll just type in the commands as they intended them to be.

Answer (score 48):

Check out [How to Install Pip article](https://jun711.github.io/devops/how-to-install-pip-on-mac-os/) for more information.

As of 2019,

Download get-pip.py provided by https://pip.pypa.io using the following command:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Run get-pip.py using the following command:
`sudo python get-pip.py`

After you done installing, run this command to check if pip is installed.
`pip --version`

Remove get-pip.py file after installing pip.
`rm get-pip.py`

[image: Pip website]

Comment: Or `curl -L get-pip.io | sudo python`.

Answer (score 34):

Install Python latest version as given [here](https://penandpants.com/2012/03/01/install-python-2/)

It has many download links like numpy and scipy

Then go to terminal and enter following command:-

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

For Python install packages [check this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

> Requirements for Installing Packages
>   This section describes the steps to follow before installing other Python packages.
>
> Install pip, setuptools, and wheel If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or
>   Python 3 >=3.4 installed from python.org, you will already have pip
>   and setuptools, but will need to upgrade to the latest version:
>
> On Linux or OS X:
>
> pip install -U pip setuptools On Windows:
>
> python -m pip install -U pip setuptools If you’re using a Python
>   install on Linux that’s managed by the system package manager (e.g
>   “yum”, “apt-get” etc…), and you want to use the system package manager
>   to install or upgrade pip, then see Installing pip/setuptools/wheel
>   with Linux Package Managers
>
> Otherwise:
>
> Securely Download get-pip.py [1](https://penandpants.com/2012/03/01/install-python-2/)
>
> Run python get-pip.py. [2](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) This will install or upgrade pip.
>   Additionally, it will install setuptools and wheel if they’re not
>   installed already.

Answer (score 30):

I spent ages going through all the answers on this page but found the one that worked for me in the comments of the OP question by [s-walsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133847/s-walsh)

The answer is to use pip3:

```
$ pip3 install <name-of-install>
```

Answer (score 24):

Installing using `apt-get` installs a system wide `pip`, not just a local one for your user.  Try this command to get pip running on your system ...

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

Then pip will be installed without any issues and you will be able to use `sudo pip...`.

Comment: This won't work as your solution is for *nix when OP specifically said "This is on Mac OS X"

Comment: Debian and ubuntu are linux distributions, this question is about mac osx, not linux.

Answer (score 21):

Most of the methods to install PIP are deprecated. Here is the latest (2019) solution. Please download get-pip script

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Run the script

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: or `curl -L https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

Answer (score 18):

#### Latest update 2021.

#### In `Ubuntu 20 64bit` works perfectly

Installation of python3

> `sudo apt install python3`

Pip Installation

> `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Add following  alias in `$HOME/.bash_aliases` in some cases file may be hidden.

> `alias pip="/usr/bin/python3 -m pip "`

Refresh current terminal session.

> `. ~/.profile`

- check pip usage: `pip`
- Install a package: `pip install {{package_name}}`

#### extra info

to get Home path

> `echo $HOME`

you will get your home path.

Answer (score 15):

To solve:

1. Add this line to `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. In a terminal window, run

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

Comment: You only need to source the bash_profile if you just made fresh changes to the file in that same terminal session. When you open any new terminals from that point on, it will already have sourced the new version.

Comment: Best answer, after trying making alias, brew install python, sudo python get-pip.py is sudo easy_install pip

Comment: This obviously only works if *(a)* your `pip` is really in `/usr/local/bin` and *(b)* remarkably, `/usr/local/bin` wasn't already on your `PATH`. Obviously, if `pip` is in a different directory (in which case it's somewhat more likely to not be on the system-provided `PATH`), adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

It might be the root permission. I tried exit root login, and use

```
sudo su -l root
pip <command>
```

Answer (score 9):

install Homebrew, open Terminal or your favorite OSX terminal emulator and run

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your ~/.profile file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Now, we can install Python 2.7:

```
$ brew install python
```

Get pip repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip
```

install pip:

```
$sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: Just `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

Python installs it by default, but if it's not installed, you can install it manually using the following command (for Linux only):

For Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

For Python 2:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Comment: Again, these commands are specific to Debian-based Linux distros, which split `python3` and `python3-pip` into separate packages for policy reasons. Other Linux systems don't have this arrangement (and don't use Apt for package management).

Answer (score 7):

If you are running Python 3.5, run the following terminal command:

```
sudo pip3 install -U nltk
```

Any other pip commands in terminal would be similar:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip3 install -U numpy ::
```

Answer (score 7):

It solved my problem by using

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 6):

Solved this by upgrading python 3  `brew upgrade python`:
 Now i can just do:

```
pip3 install  <package>  

==> python
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install/25749976#25749976) and some of the answers on this thread, I have created an alias in the rc file:
`alias pip="python3 -m pip"`

There seem to be many different answers to this question but this seems to be the best-practice approach.

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding `sudo`:

```
python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) --user
echo 'export "PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

From:

http://www.pip-command-not-found.com

Comment: Yes… the question is specifically for macOS.

Answer (score 4):

CentOS 7 users can just use:

```
yum install python-pip
```

Also recommend using `virtualenv` if you're using pip. It can be added in the same way:

```
yum install python-virtualenv
```

Comment: yum install -y python-pip python3-pip

Answer (score 4):

assuming you have internet see:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

basically run:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

and

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 4):

To overcome the issue `bash: pip: command not found` in Mac

Found two versions on Mac 1 is 2.7 and the other is 3.7

- when I say `sudo easy_install pip`, pip got installed under 2.7
- when I say `sudo easy_install-3.7 pip`, pip got installed under 3.7

But, whenever I would require to do pip install , I wanted to install the package under python3.7, so I have set an alias (`alias pip=pip3`) in `.bash_profile`.

so now, whenever I do `pip install <package_name>`, it gets installed under python3.7

Answer (score 4):

Try using this. Instead of zmq, we can use any package instead of zmq.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get update
python3 -m pip install zmq
```

I was was not able to install this zmq package in my docker image because of the same issue i was getting. So tried this as another way to install and it worked fine for me.

Comment: The `apt-get update` is not useful here. You want to run it _before_ you `apt-get install` something, not after.)

Answer (score 2):

(Context: My OS is Amazon linux using AWS. It seems similar to RedHat but it's stripped down a bit, it seems.)

Exit the shell, then open a new shell. The pip command now works.

That's what solved the problem at this location.

You might want to know as well: The pip commands to install software then needed to be written like this example (jupyter for example) to work correctly on my system:

```
pip install jupyter --user
```

Specifically, note the lack of `sudo`, and the presence of `--user`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this wasnt mentioned before, but the only thing that worked for me (on my NVIDIA Xavier) was:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

(or `sudo apt-get install python-pip` for python 2)

Comment: For Debian-based systems

Answer (score 1):

What I did to overcome this was `sudo apt install python-pip`.

It turned out my virtual machine did not have pip installed yet. It's conceivable that other people could have this scenario too.

Comment: The -1 point is because of a typo in the command that have been edited since. This solution works in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

The updated command for installing `pip3` is :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: This is obviously only true for Debian and other Debian-based Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt -y -qq install python3 python3-pip
```

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: You should never make manual changes to `/usr/bin` on systems where this location is managed by the OS or your package manager (which is to say, basically, all of them). Creating symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` instead should be totally fine. (That is, `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python` and similarly for `pip`. You want to ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is early on your `PATH`, but that should already be the case.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I had to uninstall and then reinstall pip3:

uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

`python-pip` use obsolete version of **pip** (9.0) current post pip version is (18.0) after updating pip edit `/usr/bin/pip` replace this import:

```
from pip import main
```

to

```
from pip._internal import main
```

this working for pip 18.0 problem is pip change `main` function name repeat for `/usr/bin/pip3` and `/usr/bin/pip2`

also view `/usr/local/lib/[your_python_version]/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py` It should be the same as `/usr/bin/pip`

Answer (score 0):

Do following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will surely install pip with all its dependencies. PS this is for python 3 if you want for python 2 replace python3 from the second command to python

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that your python version and the library yoıu want to install is not matching versionally. Ex: If Django is Django3 and your python version is 2.7, you may get this error.

```
After installing is running 'python' still ran Python 2.6 and PATH was not updated
```

1. Install latest version of Python
2. Change your PATH manually as python38 and compare them.
3. Try to reinstall

I solved this problem as replacing PATH manually with the latest version of Python.
As for Windows:   ;C:\python38\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows and using the Python installer, make sure to check the "Add Python to environment variables" option.

After installation, restart your shell and retry to see if `pip` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install and use the pip command in the UBUNTU terminal APP in Windows (">>" stand for UBUNTU prompt):

```
>>python3 --version 
             Python 3.6.7
>>sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
>>sudo apt-get update
>>sudo apt-get install python3-pip
>>python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install pip2 when you already have pip3:

```python
# get the installer script
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

# install pip
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora users:

`sudo dnf install python3-pip`

Other Fedora and Python related tools, read from:
[Fedora developer](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/python/python-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if Python is Installed: Pip is bundled with Python versions
   2.7.9+ and 3.4+. Open a terminal and type `python --version` or `python3 --version` to verify Python's installation. If Python is
   not installed, you must install it first.
2. `python3 -m pip install <library>`

Answer (score -2):

for new users who are yet to activate the venv for aws cli try this out

```
source venv/scripts/activate
```

then try to

```
pip install awscli
```