# How to install pip for Python 3 on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, python-3.3

OS X (Mavericks) has Python 2.7 stock installed. But I do all my own personal Python stuff with 3.3. I just flushed my 3.3.2 install and installed the new 3.3.3. So I need to install `pyserial` again. I can do it the way I've done it before, which is:

1. Download pyserial from pypi
2. untar pyserial.tgz
3. cd pyserial
4. `python3 setup.py install`

But I'd like to do like the cool kids do, and just do something like `pip3 install pyserial`. But it's not clear how I get to that point. And just that point. Not interested (unless I have to be) in virtualenv yet.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is no longer necessary as of Python3.4.** pip3 is installed as part of the general Python3 installation.

I ended up posting this same question on the python mailing list, and got the following answer:

```
# download and install setuptools
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py
python3 ez_setup.py
# download and install pip
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

Which solved my question perfectly. After adding the following for my own:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip pip
```

So that I could run pip directly, I was able to:

```
# use pip to install
pip install pyserial
```

or:

```
# Don't want it?
pip uninstall pyserial
```

Comment: to avoid confusion with `pip` that installs for Python 2.7, you could create the symlink named `pip3` instead of ambiguous `pip`

Comment: I didn't have to create a symlink, one was created automatically named pip3

Comment: Following your answer step by step solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: 404 for https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py and https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py are the updated links, though pip3 comes installed with python3 as OP mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for that update! I've been searching for so long on how to install pip, only to find that it was already on my system! Just had to use "pip3". Cheers!

Answer (score 73):

I had to go through this process myself and chose a different way that I think is better in the long run.

I installed [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then:

```
brew doctor
```

The last step gives you some warnings and errors that you have to resolve. One of those will be to download and install [the Mac OS X command-line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads).

then:

```
brew install python3
```

This gave me `python3` and `pip3` in my path.

```
pieter$ which pip3 python3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Thanks for this, was looking for a good solution.  For people seeing this in the future (who will get the same message I got from ruby), the Homebrew installer has moved and the new command is: 
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: Latest command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 66):

Install **Python3** on mac

```
1. brew install python3
2. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
3. python3
```

Use `pip3` to install modules

```
1. pip3 install ipython
2. python3 -m IPython
```

:)

Comment: Just to clarify for others, the script downloaded is from the official host for pip - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: Please add https to this example

Comment: @GardnerBickford Added https

Answer (score 34):

Here is my simple solution:

If you have python2 and python3 both installed in your system, the pip upgrade will point to python2 by default. Hence, we must specify the version of python(python3) and use the below command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This command will uninstall the previously installed pip and install the new version- upgrading your pip.

This will save memory and declutter your system.

[Image - How the upgrading of pip in Python3 works on MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojJrm.png)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for — running macOS Catalina.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved quite some efforts.

Comment: This is by far straight to the point solution!

Answer (score 15):

Plus:
when you install requests with python3, the command is:

```
pip3 install requests
```

not

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 12):

1. `brew install python3`
2. create alias in your shell profile

   - eg. `alias pip3="python3 -m pip"` in my `.zshrc`

➜  ~ pip3 --version

pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Answer (score 7):

To use Python EasyInstall (which is what I think you're wanting to use), is super easy!

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

so then with pip to install Pyserial you would do:

```
pip install pyserial
```

Comment: How does easy_install determine that it's for python3? I have a `\usr\local\bin\easy_install` dated Sep 13 2012. I'm suspicious that is from/for the stock 2.7. Sadly, `easy_install --version` isn't helpful. `--help` doesn't even give any useful hints.

Comment: @TravisGriggs - do you also have 2.7 installed? i was assuming you were only using 3.3.x.

Comment: I have not uninstalled the stock 2.7 version that is part of OSX. That would seem like a Bad Idea(tm).

Comment: @TravisGriggs, well uninstalling 2.7 can be a bad idea if not done correctly. try typing `which easy_install` in terminal following by `less <path/to/>easy_install`. It should give me more information on the version you're using.

Comment: Yeah, I had checked that. It's a binary, not a symlink. Since python3 mostly installs in `/Library/Frameworks/Python/...`, that makes me strongly suspicious that it is for 2.7.

Comment: If your pythonpath is set to use 3.3.x then easy_installing pip should associate it with the latest version — or at least that's how mine works.

Answer (score 6):

On `Mac OS X Mojave` `python` stands for python of version 2.7 and `python3` for python of version 3. The same is `pip` and `pip3`. So, to upgrade `pip` for `python 3` do this:

```
~$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, it's worth to mention that Max OSX/macOS users can just use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install pip3.

```
$> brew update
$> brew install python3
$> pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS 10.12

download pip: [pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) as `get-pip.py`

download python3: [python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

1. install python3
2. open terminal: `python3 get-pip.py`
3. `pip3` is available

Answer (score 4):

`pip` is installed automatically with python2 using brew:

1. `brew install python3`
2. `pip3 --version`

Comment: $ which pip3 python3
/usr/local/bin/python3 getting result but when I try pip3 --version then error: pip3: command not found

Answer (score 1):

simply run following on terminal if you don't have pip installed on your mac.

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

download python 3 here: [python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

once you're done with these 2 steps, make sure to run the following to verify whether you've installed them successfully.

```
python3 --version
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fresh new Mac, you need to follow below steps:-

1. Make sure you have installed `Xcode`
2. `sudo easy_install pip`
3. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
4. `brew doctor`
5. `brew doctor`
6. `brew install python3`

And you are done, just type `python3` on terminal and you will see python 3 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with python3 and pip3. Decision: solving all conflicts with links and other stuff when do

```
brew doctor
```

After that

```
brew reinstall python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MacOS 11.6 and in my case I did two things;

1. Install Python 3 from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ clicking on first link `Download macOS 64-bit universal2 installer` from Stable Releases list
2. Create alias for Python3 running the following command on Terminal `echo "alias python='/usr/bin/python3'" > ~/.bash_profile`

After that open a new terminal and type `python -V` to check if the version of python 3 is enabled by default for your use so now you can use the command `pip3` to install your packages like `pip3 install somepackage`

Answer (score 0):

use [port](https://ports.macports.org/port/py38-pip/) to install it, it is better than brew, in case you have an old machine.

```
sudo port install py38-pip
```