# Beautiful Soup 4 Import

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm getting an import error on this line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It says:

```
ImportError: no module named 'bs4'
```

Any idea what's going on / how to fix this?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Not totally sure what's going on here re: comments.  Link says there are two comments but I can't view any...

Comment: This means that you didn't install bs4, so you have to install it http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Comment: Well I did that and got this back: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...

Comment: @puciek, please see above!

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It may be selecting a different python instance than the one where you installed bs4 to. Also, after installing a packing, make sure to close out of and re-open any python interpreters.

Comment: no ide, just vim.  python interpreters?  i'm just using iterm...

Comment: There are probably several python installation on your machine. Print `sys.path` to see what paths are used to look for Python modules

Answer (score 0):

[`import sys; print(sys.path)` shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572649/beautiful-soup-4-import/22573636#comment34374445_22573636) that you use Python 3.3 but [the output from `pip` shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572649/beautiful-soup-4-import/22573636#comment34360620_22572649) that it installs for Python 2.7

Use `pip` that installs for Python 3.3. It might be already installed as `pip3` or `pip3.3`. If not; then [install it first](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Comment: so I get to this page: https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py and have 0 idea what to do with it...mind providing a bit of guidance?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Mariogs: [how to install pip for python3 on mac os x](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20082935/4279)

Comment: Ah ok, just followed that.  No error messages when installing pip for python3.  I still have the "requirement already satisfied" message when I run 'pip install beautifulsoup4'.  What am I missing?  Thanks again

Comment: @Mariogs: do you understand that there may be *two* different `pip` scripts on your system? Create a symlink named `pip3` if it does not already exist for the `pip` that you installed for Python 3.3

Comment: Yes, I get that.  By "symlink" do you mean an alias in my bash profile?  I'm not exactly sure how to specify one for the pip I installed for Python 3.3

Comment: @Mariogs: what happens if you put "symlink" in google

Comment: Looks like they're the same as aliases on Mac.  I think my confusion is this: if I create an alias named 'pip3', what string am I setting that equal to in order to access the pip I installed for Python 3?

Comment: @Mariogs: symlink is not an alias. Look for `ln -s` command in [the installation instructions linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20082935/4279). Run `which pip` and see if it gives you any ideas about the Python version (look for 2.7 and 3.3 in the path). Or run `head -1 $(which pip)` to see the shebang.