# Python version messing with my BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

So I just downloaded get-pip.py and ran it.  Everything looks good (I got "successfully installed pip").

When I run:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

So it looks like I have beautifulsoup4 set up for python 2.7...yes?  I want it set up for python 3.3 (which is what I get when I type python into iTerm).  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Feel like it shouldn't be terribly difficult but have looked around to no avail

Thanks guys,
Mariogs

Comment: do you have easy_install-3?

Comment: googled around but can't find how to check... :(

Comment: when you type pip in the terminal, press tab to see what options you have. do the same with easy_install

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install for a specific version using that version's pip

```
pip-3.3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: When I run "pip -V" I get: pip 1.5.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)...and when I run "pip-3.3 install beautifulsoup4" I get: command not found...

Comment: @Mariogs you may have `pip-3` if not it should be apt-get-able or yum-able depending on your distribution.  Try typing `pip` at a terminal and tabbing to see what it autocompletes with

Comment: I get "pip     pip2    pip2.7"

Comment: @Mariogs what linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm on a mac, OS X 10.9.3

Comment: @Mariogs hmm.  either [get pip3 for mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python3-on-mac-os-x) or use another suggestion to install without pip, though I can't say I know much about how mac works with installing programs via command line

Answer (score 0):

Simillarly Download Beautifulsoup into ur system untar it  then type

```
pyton3.3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have pip3 installed do the following:

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3 distribute_setup.py
```

Add

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:$PATH
to your    .bash_profile
```

Then restart terminal and `sudo  pip install beautifulsoup4`