# I don't know how to update my Python version to 3.4?

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I'm on OSX, and I installed IDLE for Python 3.4. However, in Terminal my `python -V` and `pip --version` are both Python 2.7.

How do I fix this? I really have no idea how any of this works, so please bear with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: `python` is the system Python version. Are there `python3` and `python3.4` commands?

Comment: You may just have to download and install a new python.

Comment: @James_Parsons I downloaded IDLE for Python 3.4, as I said.  I though I already had Python 3.4 installed.  I can run scripts in it in IDLE.

Comment: How did you install IDLE?

Comment: On the Python.org website, I went to the downloads page and clicked the "Install Python 3.4 Mac OSX" button.

Comment: The provided answer should work, but if you want to be able to just run `python` and run python 3, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/mac-set-default-python-version-to-3-3

Answer (score 0):

Try `python3` or `python3.4`. It should print out the right version if correctly installed.

Python 3.4 already has pip with it. You can use `python3 -m pip` to access pip. Or `python3 -m ensurepip` to make sure that it's correctly installed.

Comment: Okay, it does that.  Now how do I update pip so that it installs things for Python 3 rather than Python 2?  You didn't really answer my question...

Comment: @DrewNolan: Python 3.4 includes `pip`; you can use `python3.4 -m pip ...` to access the bundled version.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Python3, you can use `python3` to run python programs(or use a shebang). Python 3 also install pip. If you find your Python3 installed version of pip try to `alias` the `pip` command to the newer pip. Check this out for more info:

[How to install pip for Python 3 on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python3-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that making the 'python' alias replace the default version of python that the system comes with is a bad idea.

When you install a new version of python (3.4 for instance), 
these two new commands are installed, specifically for the version you installed:

pip3.4

python3.4

If you're using an IDE that wants you to indicate which python version you are using the IDE will let you navigate to it in the Library folder

pip will still be for python2.7 after you download some other python version, as I think that's the current version osx comes installed with