# Querying MSSQL server 2012 from a Raspberry Pi 3 using Python, FreeTDS and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, raspberry-pi, pyodbc, freetds

I am trying to query MSSQL server 2012 using Python as my scripting language on a raspberry Pi3.

I have the need to create an application that will query MSSQL server and return some values that need to be displayed on a H.M.I. I chose the Raspberry Pi platform to develop this solution using Python as the programming language. I created the script using PyCharm on a Windows 7 PC and all worked well. When I moved it to the Raspberry Platform it didn't work.

I am using pyODBC to do the connecting and querying and FreeTDS as the driver. I used the following procedure to set this up:

```
 sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
 pip3 install pyODBC
```

Configured the /etc/freetds.conf file as follows

```
 [NAME]
 host = ipAddress
 port = 1433
 tds version = 7.4
 instance = dbInstanceName
```

I then went to the command line and tested the connection with: `tsql -S NAME -U username`. The command line then prompts with `Password:` so I typed the password in and I got the following:

```
 locale is "enGB.UTF-8"
 locale charset is "UTF-8"
 using default charset "UTF-8"
 1>
```

As there are no errors present I can only assume that this has worked?

I then set up the /etc/odbcinst.ini file as follows:

```
 [FreeTDS]
 Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

I then setup the  /etc/odbc.ini file as follows:

```
 [NAME1]
 Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
 Description = MSSQL Server
 Trace = No
 Server = ipAddress
 Database = dbName
 Port = 1433
 TDS_Version = 7.4
```

I then tested this with the isql function in the command line: `isql NAME1 user password` and I got the following prompt:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Connected!
|
| sql-statement
| help [tablename] 
| quit
|
+-------------------------------------------------+

SQL>
```

so I typed in `select getDate()` and the date and time returned.

However within Python I still can't get a connection, I typed the following into the interpreter:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=NAME;DATABASE=dbName;UID=user;PWD=password')
```

Then when I type this `cu = conn.cursor()` I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute cursor
```

Comment: Did you set the NAME, dbName, user and password values for your connection to be successful? Hint: https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1293636#file-hello_pyodbc-py

Comment: Also please note that the connect function gets a single string as parameter.

Comment: Hi BoboDarph,Thank you for your reply, I did set the user and password to the real values.

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Raspberry pi2 & Python 3 with Raspbian & MS Sql server 2008

> Make sure your APT-Get library & Python Version is up to date ”

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Sudo apt-get install python3
```

> Run following commands to install requirements

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
sudo apt-get install tdsodbc
sudo apt-get install freetds-bin
```

> In terminal, now run :(use 'pip3'  because pyodbc wouldn’t install for pip (python 2) due to some errors)

```
sudo pip3 install pyodbc
sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc
```

> Change freeTDS.conf like this

```
sudo nano /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

Add a block like this :

[sqlserver]
      host = 182.172.2.2    # Remote Sql Server's IP addr
      port = 1433           # this is default
      tds version = 7.0     # this is by the time i post this
      instance = Test1      # your Database name
```

> Then set up the /etc/odbcinst.ini file as follows:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount = 1
```

> Then setup the /etc/odbc.ini file as follows:

```
[NAME1]
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Description = MSSQL Server
Trace = No
Server = Server2      # IP or host name of the Sql Server
Database = Test1      # DataBase Name
Port = 1433           # This is default
TDS_Version = 7.4
```

> Now test the connection with this commands (with second one you should get command line access to Sql server

```
tsql -S sqlserver -U username
isql NAME1 user 'password'
```

And finally the code part :

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};Server=Server2;PORT=1433;DATABASE=Test1;UID=user;PWD=pass;TDS_Version=7.2;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from Table1")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Finally if nothing worked try this :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tdsodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Ill try to connect a RPi 3 to my DB in SQL Server, to capture GPIO status/value.

I already using a web server called Webiopi, and python is used to execute macros, and define GPIO function/Value.

It can be possible?

```
If(possible == yes)
  {
     happiness = happiness + 10;
     return view(success)
  }
else
  {
     happines = 0;
     return view(keep_searching);
  }
```

TY

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your connection string. Here's a full connection string example for FreeTDS:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yourfqdn.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=your_db;UID=your_username;PWD=your_pw;TDS_Version=7.4;'
)
```

Try putting `{FreeTDS}` in braces and adding the `TDS_Version` explicitly. I also choose to use the FQDN in my Python connection strings and set username / password as environment variables to keep configuration in one less place.

Comment: Hi FlipperPA, Thank you for your reply. I have now changed my connection string to 'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=ipAddress;PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbName;UID=user;PWD=password;TDS_Version=7.4;' but unfortunately it still won't connect!

Comment: I'm betting you don't have FreeTDS 1.0, which was the first to support `TDS_Version=7.4`. Can you try `TDS_Version=7.1` instead, and if it works, try 7.2 and 7.3? If you let me know what version of FreeTDS you're running (with `tsql -C`) I can tell you for sure what the maximum supported TDS version is.

Comment: Hi FlipperPA, Thank you for your reply. You are right I have version 0.91 installed. There is another line which reads TDS Version 4.2

Comment: One other thing I have the ipAdress explicitly declared as SERVER=192.168.4.212 does this need to be in braces?

Comment: Only the `DRIVER={Driver}` needs to be in braces. Version `0.91` has a maximum supported `TDS_Version` of `7.2`. I have a PR in for this, but the documentation hasn't been updated yet: https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/pull/71/files The `TDS Version 4.2` is from the `[global]` settings in `freetds.conf`. Passing `TDS_Version=7.2` in the `pyodbc.connect()` string should override this.

Comment: I have now changed the TDS_Version to 7.1 but unfortunately it still doesn't connect. I have successfully queried the database using the isql and tsql commands from the command prompt so I assume this proves that the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini is configured correctly and the freedtds.conf is also configured correctly.