# pyodbc.Error: ('01000',"[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager] can't open lib '/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc/so' : file not Found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, raspberry-pi4, freetds

I have followed [Querying MSSQL from RaspberryPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969924/querying-mssql-server-2012-from-a-raspberry-pi-3-using-python-freetds-and-pyodb) to install FreeTDS on my Pi4. However, the error below occurs.
['FreeTDS']

Traceback (most recent call last ):

File "/home/pi/Downloads/test1.py" , line 14,

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC] [Driver Manager]

can't open lib '/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsobc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: Which instructions? There is no accepted answer at the SO question you linked.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, copy the original text to your question. And definitely don't take pictures of the screen with a camera.

Comment: Yes I have changed already.

Comment: The `/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsobc.so` path seems to be incorrect. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73781324/edit) your question to include the contents of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`.

Comment: Yes I have got it. The library location in my raspberry pi is different from the tutorial and I don't know how to find that location but now I have got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/odbcinst.ini

If the paths for Driver and Setup do not work in your installation, you can find where these files are located by running find / -name "libtds*".