# I can't download any module from Python3 in Mac

Tags: python, macos, module, pip, urllib

I was trying to download a module using `pip3`, and I wasn't able to because of some simple error. Now, I'm not sure what I did, but I can't downaload any module in my computer. I've tried everything:
`sudo pip3 install urllib3`
`pip3 install urllib3`
`pip3 install selenium`
and a lot more. I don't know what to do. Maybe I erased a python file and now I can't download any module.
Here is the end of the error I get in the terminal when I try to run `sudo pip3 install selenium`, after I put my password: `No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3`.

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pip? Have a look at [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261)

Comment: Yes, but I get this:
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-42592.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in

Comment: (continuing):
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: @pecey I took a look at that, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do. Could you please help me? For that who helps me I promise, I'll improve your reputation by a LOT

Comment: Are you trying to use pip3 with python2.7? If you don't have root access, one way out might be to create a local environment, so the packages are installed locally. Does `pip3 install --user selenium` work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure, I already downloaded Python3, but I seem to be using python2.7 to download. I tried what you told me, but I get this: ` No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3`

Comment: ```
Nicolas-MBP:python nicolasfuchs$ python --version
Python 2.7.16

Nicolas-MBP:python nicolasfuchs$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.3
```

Comment: Here is my version, but when I try downloading it uses python 2.7, is there a way to override this?

Comment: Can you try `sudo python3 -m pip install selenium`, if successful, then test with `python3 -m selenium`

Comment: Ok, I'm trying!

Comment: I tried it, but I got this: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3' @Philippe

Comment: Can you type `type python3`, to see where you python3 is ?

Comment: I think `python3` is pointing correctly, since the version was 3.8 as posted in a previous comment. But weird that `python3 -m pip` failed too. Can you type `type pip3` and then `cat <the location returned by the previous command>`? It should ideally be using the shebang for python3

Comment: @Philippe: python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Comment: @pecey I did what you told me, now what?

Comment: @pecey and philippe I think the problem is with this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'

Comment: Can you try to delete `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/site-packages/pip` and then try reinstalling pip using `python3 -m ensurepip`, followed by `pip3 install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Everything I try I get this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'

Comment: How can I download module pip._vendor.urllib3. Or I get this: ImportError: cannot import name urllib3 (**Please @pecey can you help me**)

Comment: Maybe try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340173/2125671