python - macOS Sequoia: reading plist
trying to read plist in macOS sequoia. I did find https://pypi.org/project/plists/#description but it doesn't install
How can I use python plists package?

pip3 install plists

Gives the following error:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting plists
  Using cached plists-0.0.4.tar.gz (7.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_4670f12a38cc4539a382c3ec2a0ed312/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_4670f12a38cc4539a382c3ec2a0ed312/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-iufqpu7j
         cwd: /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_4670f12a38cc4539a382c3ec2a0ed312/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_4670f12a38cc4539a382c3ec2a0ed312/setup.py", line 80
        print "PDIR: ", pdir(), os.listdir(pdir())
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/1b/24d3f3885744b41e4d58774bce89b3a20966960cd41c9d3d787485e01e1d/plists-0.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=d48b2390c27d957cf54791001f679f1c96d2652b599a85a3d9d2cc4567c02ce0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/plists/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached plists-0.0.3.tar.gz (6.9 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_b5366a04f87f4cc0be570288a1a967b6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_b5366a04f87f4cc0be570288a1a967b6/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-qqjk06qw
         cwd: /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_b5366a04f87f4cc0be570288a1a967b6/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_b5366a04f87f4cc0be570288a1a967b6/setup.py", line 80
        print "PDIR: ", pdir(), os.listdir(pdir())
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/bf/d7e74c38a6d8d4993ac2631fc327c3439e06e7d01ebf54f86202393e548f/plists-0.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=c3ac16d5b6262552ac5da8ac410fa7a85e918e11ff708cf5b4958f240619029b (from https://pypi.org/simple/plists/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached plists-0.0.2.tar.gz (6.9 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_accf278426034dce9e1b20c280eb6e51/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_accf278426034dce9e1b20c280eb6e51/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-y01b3lan
         cwd: /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_accf278426034dce9e1b20c280eb6e51/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_accf278426034dce9e1b20c280eb6e51/setup.py", line 80
        print "PDIR: ", pdir(), os.listdir(pdir())
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/38/e451a4895d12d241f2bca8061a2d5c4d376e2e90739d892977a1266e227f/plists-0.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=ed39b1dad1b0de1dfc4853e70c39bd7a14e5e3b7b86ad76c22754d49833976fd (from https://pypi.org/simple/plists/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached plists-0.0.1.tar.gz (6.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_6072274ea7ea4f6bafbe428f95e5feb1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_6072274ea7ea4f6bafbe428f95e5feb1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-8esq59jv
         cwd: /private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_6072274ea7ea4f6bafbe428f95e5feb1/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/9j/s_r_lpgs2tj1v838wj4h716c0000gn/T/pip-install-eh0uq6op/plists_6072274ea7ea4f6bafbe428f95e5feb1/setup.py", line 80
        print "PDIR: ", pdir(), os.listdir(pdir())
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/67/18ade2a5d79733595d53a0ae174bdf11d28ac2f649db68b2377148291ad8/plists-0.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=3c452ad85861ada94f3199658c0fadd860a3c74388346e9c58ff74132807e893 (from https://pypi.org/simple/plists/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plists (from versions: 0.0.3.macosx-10.10-x86_64, 0.0.4.macosx-10.10-x86_64, 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plists
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 24.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-on-mac-os-x
And please can you type pip3 --version then post your output

pip3 is installed by default.  command: pip3 --version
result: pip 21.2.4 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

print "PDIR: ", pdir(), os.listdir(pdir()) is Python2 syntax. Probably the library wasn't updated since years and is not compatible with Python3.

Looks like this package is already merged into python3 - https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html
import plistlib
file_name = "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist"
with open(file_name, 'rb') as infile:
    plist = plistlib.load(infile)
print(plist["LastConfigurationTraceDate"])


It looks like your issue might be coming from the version of pip3 you have 21.2.4, I suggest you update it to version 24.3.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plists (from versions: 0.0.3.macosx-10.10-x86_64, 0.0.4.macosx-10.10-x86_64, 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plists

“My assumption here” is that you have your Python library, not in Homebrew. Therefore, I’ll advise you to take the virtual environment route
cd into the venv path where you have your python3, which I suppose should be here
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
then take the steps below
Step 1
sudo python3.13 -m venv path/to/venv
Step 2
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
Step 3
sudo python3.13 -m pip install --upgrade pip or pip install --upgrade pip
After which you can go ahead and install you plists package
pip3 install plists 
This should get you up to speed

after upgrading the pip3 to 24.3.1 a lot of the errors got removed but plists still didn't install see jsfiddle.net/oLbatfh7

Oh @Lacer Sadly I'm just seeing your comment. It sounds like a package issue then
