# how do i install pip on python 3.5.2?

Tags: python

i downloaded python 3.5.2, i am planning on making a keylogger i need to install pyhook and pywin but i dont know how. every body recommends me to install it by pip but i dont seem to have that module. i open up the idle and import pip, but it gives me the error message saying i dont have that module installed even though people say pip comes with versions 3.4+..  where and how do i install this pip module? i am on a windows ver. 10, 64 bits, python 3.5. any help is aprecciated.. i am new by the way go easy on me..

Comment: pip isn't a module.  It's an executable program that you invoke *outside* of Python.

Comment: @Makoto Correct. You don't need to use `pip` within a python script, you simply do `pip install pyhook` etc. in a terminal. However, I just tried to `import pip` in python 3 and it _does_ work. So if OP can't do that then there might indeed be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the `pip` executable is in your `%PATH%` variable. For me, the `pip` executable is located in the `Scripts` directory of my Python installation. That turned out to be `C:\Python34\Scripts`. So you should find out where this location is for you and then add it to your path variable.

[Useful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328818/python-2-7-cannot-pip-on-windows-bash-pip-command-not-found).

Comment: when i installed python 3.5 i selected the option for it to add to path and it said pip was included aswell but i go to comand prompt type in everyway for it to pop up and nothing. the message error is either syntax, module not found or specific route unknown.. should i downgrade to 2.7? maybe 3.5 just isnt compatible with windows 10.

Comment: I would just make sure that it's there by manually editing your path variable.

Comment: i set my laziness aside and did it.. thank you so much.

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct so that others know what worked to fix your problem :).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when pip is not installed by default, use this:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 3.4 and was getting the error that it didn't exist. I ran this upgrade and I can now import pyperclip which was one of the packages in that module.

```
C:\Python35-32\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Output:

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |################################| 1.2MB 259kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2
```