# ModuleNotFoundError Eventhough package is installed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm currently trying to install grovepi for a sensor that I need for my Raspberry Pi. But I constantly get a module not found error, even though I know for sure it's installed.

I've already tried to uninstall and install cython multiple times, but with no success. When I type `pip list` it shows that `Cython` is within the list, yet I still get the same error.

No matter what I seem to do, it insists that the module cannot be found. My question is, am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something here? Is the problem within the package?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Error

```
Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

**Package I'm trying to install**

```
curl -kL dexterindustries.com/update_grovepi | bash
```

Comment: Not sure if these will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572773/pip-is-not-uninstalling-packages , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832219/pip-not-working-in-python-installation-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem doesn't seem to be with pip, as the package is getting installed but for some reason when installing `update_grovepi` it doesn't see it.