# Selenium explicit waits (importing folder)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-module

[I'm new to the site and the website wouldn't let me upload my question because i didnt "indent my code" which I have. I spent 1.5h trying to type my question, so i decided to use screen shot. I need help with Selenium Explicit Waits.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJQEs.png)

**[EDIT]:I realised I was using python idle 3.6 instead of idle 2.7. SMH sorry for wasting everyone's time. this is why it wouldn't run.**

Links to websites:

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automate-create-login-bot-python-selenium/

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Please check out the question.
Thank you.

Comment: How / Where did you install Selenium?

Comment: Did follow "Installation and Setup" step from that guide? You need to install Selenium.  If you have a trouble with `pip install selenium` ending with message “pip is not recognized as an internal or external command” look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328818/python-2-7-cannot-pip-on-windows-bash-pip-command-not-found/25331771#25331771

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm going to try to answer with some assumptions.

I assume that you are new like me and had no concept of pip install.

Generally, if you are new, you think of downloading and pressing an exe. file to install something. You **probably**(I did) tried something like this and installed it incorrectly. Pip install tends to be very consistent and avoid making this an issue.

I find this to be a general benign issue with the coding community if you're brand new. There's just so many concepts that are taken for granted that explanation to beginners tends to be not so great. You have to be very specific and give a lot of context and your own thought processes to even type the right question.

Here are the steps:

1.Find where your python folder is located and write down the path:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
```

2.Click on your windows start button and type "cmd" in the search bar and click on it to open that wonderful black box.

3.Now copy paste the address and add '\pip install selenium and hit enter

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip install selenium
```

All you need to now is wait for it to tell you to that it was successful. There are other functions for pip like uninstalling, updating and etc. Just so you know. Sometimes one of the annoying things for me is making sure I have the right term/name when I use pip install. Keep in mind that not everything is installed through pip, just most of the things you will use probably.

More examples:

```
 C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip install numpy
 C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip install openpyxl
 C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip install <libraryname>
```

---

This is the video that taught me how to install things:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc

Comment: Thanks bro, the video you linked will come in handy.