# Cannot create and activate a virtual environment on Git Bash with Python 2.7, Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on windows with python 2.7 and I want to work in a virtual environment.

When I type

```
virtualenv venv
```

Bash says

> bash: virtualenv: command not found

That makes me think virtualenv is not installed, then I try to install virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

But again Bash says

> bash: pip: command not found

Then by reading this thread [python 2.7: cannot pip on windows "bash: pip: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328818/python-2-7-cannot-pip-on-windows-bash-pip-command-not-found/25331771) I find out that it cannot find the pip directory, that maybe is the same reason for which it cannot find virtualenv directory.
So I specify the path of pip and I try again to instal virtualenv

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

It installs virtualenv but then tells

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7.

So I go forward and try to activate my virtualenv by typing

```
virtualenv venv
```

and as I expected I get the same error of before

> bash: virtualenv: command not found

that I try to solve in the same way I did for pip, by typing

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

and this time bash responds with

> $ python -m virtualenv venv New python executable in
>   C:\Users\Tommaso\DJANGO~1\UDEMYD~1\METAGL~2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel... done.

So I guess it created my virtualenv named venv, but in my bash terminal I still get the writing "(master)" at the end of the input line, that I guess it means the virtual environment is not active.
How do I activate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!
Here is what I did.

First, by following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243261/7658051), I found out how to make Git Bash use python 3.7 instead of python 2.7 by default:

I opened the file `aliases.sh` with Notepad++, located at

> C:<path where you installed Git Bash>\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh

Under the paragraph

> ### --show-control-chars: help showing Korean or accented characters

I added these lines indicating where the two versions of python I want to switch are located

```
alias python2='C:/<installation_path_of_python_2.7>/Python 2.7/python.exe' 
alias python='C:/<installation_path_of_python_3.7>/Python 3.7/python.exe' 

alias pip='C:/<installation_path_of_python_3.7>/Phyton/Scripts/pip.exe' 
alias virtualenv='C:/<installation_path_of_python_3.7>/Phyton/Scripts/virtualenv.exe'
```

You don't really need the last 2 ones, but it will help you a lot, since it enables Git Bash to call pip, virtualenv and other scripts without writing `python -m` before the name of the script.

You can check out if you did right by typing

```
python -i
```

It should return you the latest python version you specified.

Then if I type

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

It installs the virtual environment in the current directory

To activate that, just type

```
. venv/scripts/activate
```

If it works, you should see

> (venv)

near to your active input line.

To deactivate it just type

```
deactivate
```

Comment: In the end I would recommend to use Anaconda instead of Bash, if one is using Windows. I think Bash is plenty of bugs when it runs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. The solution is to install virtualenv first using pip. Then:

1. enter virtualenv nameOfTheEnvironment
2. nameOfTheEnvironment\Scripts\activate

You should see something like:

````
C:\Users\bamidele\Documents\DjangoProjects>virtualenv venv

created virtual environment CPython3.7.2.final.0-64 in 15334ms
creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\bamidele\Documents\DjangoProjects\venv, clear=False, global=False)seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\bamidele\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\seed-app-data\v1.0.1)activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator


C:\Users\bamidele\Documents\DjangoProjects>venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) C:\Users\bamidele\Documents\DjangoProjects>```

I hope this solves your problem.
````

Answer (score 0):

In git bash, cd into the virtual environment(venv) directory of your project and use this command

```
source ./Scripts/activate
```

to activate virtual environment(venv)[image: exampe]

Answer (score 0):

You can go

```
cd venv\Scripts
```

path. Then:

Run the command

```
activate
```

This run on my Flask project.