# What's the difference between "pip install" and "python -m pip install"?

Tags: python, pip

I have a local version of Python 3.4.1 and I can run `python -m pip install`, but I'm unable to find the pip binary to run `pip install`. What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing, assuming `pip` is using the same version of Python as the `python` executable. The docs for distributing Python modules were [just updated](http://bugs.python.org/issue22295) to suggest using `python -m pip` instead of the `pip` executable, because it allows you to be explicit about which version of Python to use. In systems with more than one version of Python installed, it's not always clear which one `pip` is linked to.

---

Here's some more concrete "proof" that both commands should do the same thing, beyond just trusting my word and the bug report I linked :)

If you take a look at the `pip` executable script, it's just doing this:

```
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
<snip>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
```

It's calling [`load_entry_point`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#convenience-api), which returns a function, and then executing that function. The entry point it's using is called `'console_scripts'`. If you look at the entry_points.txt file for `pip` (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4.egg-info/entry_points.txt on my Ubuntu machine), you'll see this:

```
[console_scripts]
pip = pip:main
pip2.7 = pip:main
pip2 = pip:main
```

So the entry point returned is the `main` function in the `pip` module.

When you run `python -m pip`, you're executing the `__main__.py` script inside the `pip` package. That looks like this:

```
import sys
from .runner import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit = run()
    if exit:
        sys.exit(exit)
```

And the `runner.run` function looks like this:

```
def run():
    base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    ## FIXME: this is kind of crude; if we could create a fake pip
    ## module, then exec into it and update pip.__path__ properly, we
    ## wouldn't have to update sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, base)
    import pip
    return pip.main()
```

As you can see, it's just calling the `pip.main` function, too. So both commands end up calling the same `main` function in `pip/__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where can I corroborate that info? And where are the packages installed using the local Python?

Comment: And this "concept" does not only apply to `pip`, but also other Python "command line tools" can be called like this. E.g., `python -m markdown`. To quote from the python help menu `-m mod : run library module as a script`

Comment: @ilciavo: small correction: `python -m pip` runs `pip/__main__.py` module, not `pip/__init__.py`. It is a general rule: `python -m module` runs `module.__main__` module if `module` is a package (has `__path__` attribute) otherwise it runs the `module` itself -- both with `__name__=="__main__"`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, you're right. I've corrected that in my answer.

Comment: For some reason if I try doing `python2.6 -m pip install` I get `/usr/bin/python: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: @ilciavo Can you `import pip` at all when you run `python2.6`?

Comment: Yes I can `import pip` but I can't `python -m pip install` on python 2.6

Comment: @ilciavo Looks like that is a limitation of Python 2.6. It doesn't support using packages with the `-m` flag. You'll have to use `python -m pip.__main__` directly.

Comment: @jfs just for clarification, `python -m module` runs both `module/__init__.py` and `module/__main__.py` if the `module` is a package.

Comment: @starriet: it imports the module (`__name__ == "module"`) but it doesn't run it. For comparison, `-m package` does run `package/__main__.py` -> `__name__ == "__main__"`). btw, `-m module` likely imports other modules too (add `-v`, to see them).

Comment: @jfs I mentioned `-m package`, not import. `-m package` runs both `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`, doesn't it?

Comment: @starriet: `-m package` does not "run" `__init__.py` that you can see by inspecting `__name__` (if you see `__main__` then the code is "running" if you see (for the exact same module, exact same module) just its name then it is just an import.

Comment: They only do the same thing if they're set up that way. It's possible to have a messy setup where `pip` runs in a different interpreter than `python` refers to. That's why `python -m` is the recommended way. So you could edit the first paragraph to say *"They **should** do exactly the same thing, **but** the docs ... because **then you can tell which interpreter** is going to be used ..."*

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for that suggestion. I used different wording, but I updated my answer to make it clear that they only do the exact same thing if they're targeting the same version of Python.

Answer (score 27):

**2021**

**This only happens if you create the venv with PyCharm. Please check if Scripts/pip-script.py located in your virtual environment**

`pip install` and `python -m pip install` -- is not really the same. Or welcome back into the **HELL of VERSIONING & DEPENDENCIES** :-(

I was used to type `pip(.exe) install <name>` if I want install a package. But I run into trouble, if I try to install package Pillow. It breaks every time with an error message.

Today I retry `python -m pip install` copy&pasted from the manual and it works. Before I ignored it and type pip.... Because I thought it is the same.

I start to dive a little bit deeper into pip and I find this question/answer. After a while I found that pip.exe calls the script <virtual-environment/Scripts>pip-script.py.

I fighting with the installation of package Pillow.

```
#! .\venv\Scripts\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==19.0.3','console_scripts','pip3'
__requires__ = 'pip==19.0.3'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==19.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
    )
```

I was a little bit surprised that pip.exe still use the old version 19.0.3 of the package and not the new installed version 21.0.1.

I changed the two version strings by hand to 21.0.1. And now pip.exe was able to install Pillow proper.

From now I understand why pip still complains that I use an old version of pip.

[image]

I think the old v19 pip has problem to detect the supported platform and therefore sources instead of binaries are installed.

Comment: The highest voted answer backs up the answer concrete examples. To disagree with the poster would be more compelling if you built a more concrete case- your example of Pillow seems to be a tangent to answering the question at hand. Would using `python -m pip` have solved the Pillow issue? Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @AllenM Thank you for your answer. I investigate again and I found out that pip-script.py is coming from PyCharm if I create a virtual environment with it. If I create the venv with command-line (python -m venv venv) this script missing in folder Scripts.

Answer (score 10):

Every installation of Python potentially comes with its own version of Pip. (Some installations may deliberately exclude Pip for security reasons: for example, when Python is included in a Linux distribution, it commonly omits Pip so that the user will not inadvertently install something harmful into a copy of Python that the operating system depends on.)

Conceptually, Pip consists of two pieces: the `pip` standard library module, contained in a `pip.py` file; and a `pip` "wrapper" executable. (On Windows this is implemented as an actual .exe file; on Mac and Linux, it should simply be a Python script that has execution privileges set and which does not have a `.py` filename extension.) The purpose of the wrapper is to run the "main" code in the corresponding standard library module.

Using `pip` at the command line will find and run **whichever wrapper executable** is first in the PATH environment variable, which will then run the corresponding Python code *for the installation of Python associated with that wrapper*. Therefore, it will install third-party libraries for whichever Python that is.

Using `python -m pip` at the command line will find and run **whichever Python** is first in the PATH environment variable, and instruct it to find the `pip` standard library module *in its* standard library (not directly; it will search `sys.path` just like with any module import) and run it "[as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001)". Therefore, it will install third-party libraries for the Python that was found in the PATH.

On Windows, using `py -m pip` at the command line will (unless the system is badly misconfigured) find and run [**the `py` executable**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), which is installed to a Windows directory that will always be on the PATH. This, in turn, will [*use its own logic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824903) to choose a Python on the system, run *its* `pip`, and from there it proceeds as before.

Depending on how the system is configured, **these commands might not all choose the same Python installation**.

Using `python -m pip` ensures that libraries are installed for *the same Python that would run, using `python myscript.py`*. This is very useful for those who are writing `myscript.py`, need that code to use the library that will be installed, and want it to run with whichever `python` that is.

As a special note for Windows, **`pip install --upgrade pip` will not work**. [This is because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473) upgrading Pip involves replacing the Pip wrapper executable on disk; by running the command this way, that wrapper executable *is the program that is running*, and Windows disallows programs from replacing themselves on disk. By using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, or `py -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead, the problem is avoided, because now the wrapper executable does not run - Python (and possibly also `py`) runs, using code from the `pip.py` (or a cached `pip.pyc`) file.

Comment: Thanks for the update and details about Windows

Comment: One quibble: `pip` is not a [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip`: runs the pip module as a python script

`pip`: runs the pip executable

Usually these are installed together and point to the same python script. So in most cases, you can use either form of the command and they will achieve the same result. However, using `python -m pip` ensures that libraries are installed for the same Python instance that would run e.g.  `python <script.py>`. If in a virtual environment, this will be the python version the "activate" command set up. Some virtual environments may or may not setup a new path for pip. Therefore being explicit with `python -m pip` is usually preferred.

If you want to test to make sure they are found correctly on your path:

Windows:

```
where python
where pip
```

Linux:

```
which python
which pip
```

Note: venv will setup a path to pip as well for an activate environment.