# py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --cov=ner_brands --cov-report=term-missing --cov-config

Tags: python, pytest

when I am trying to run my test through command line

```
py.test  file_name.py
```

I got this error:

```
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --cov=ner_brands --cov-report=term-missing --cov-config
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In case you are looking for the apt command apt install python-coverage

Answer (score 258, accepted):

[pytest-cov package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov) is required if you want to pass --cov arguments to pytest, by default it should not be passed though. Are you using a modified version of py.test?

```
pip install pytest-cov
```

would fix your issue.

Comment: If you're still getting this issue look at @Samuel Phan's answer bellow.

Comment: This does not fix my issue, nor the one below. I am using Python 2.7.17, py.test==3.2.2 and pytest-cov==2.5.1 on Windows 7

Comment: Sampe problem suddenly. pytest-cov is already installed.

Answer (score 12):

For those who use CentOS 6, the version of `setuptools` is old and you need to upgrade it also:

```
pip install pytest-cov
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Just after installing `pip install pytest-cov`:

```
~ # py.test --version
This is pytest version 3.0.5, imported from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytest.pyc

~ # pip install --upgrade setuptools
[...]
Successfully installed setuptools-30.3.0

~ # py.test --version
This is pytest version 3.0.5, imported from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytest.pyc
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-cov-2.4.0 at /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py
```

Answer (score 9):

If the other answers here didn't work for you, you may have py.test installed somewhere else in your system. In my case, I ran into the issue described here inside a virtual environment, but it turned out that pytest was defaulting to my system installation (which did not have pytest-cov installed).

Deactivate your virtual environment or start a new shell and run the following to confirm:

```
pip3 freeze | grep pytest
```

(or `pip freeze | grep pytest` if you're running python2)

If you find it, try uninstalling it, then reactivate your virtual environment and try again.

Answer (score 5):

sdonk's answer helped me. But since I use pipenv, I had to run

```
pipenv install pytest_cov
```

Comment: I tried this with `pipenv` and it didn't work. This will still install and display `pytest-cov` in the `Pipfile`.

Comment: `pip install pytest_cov` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

On my Ubuntu, I had also similar issue which was caused by having wrong binary for `pytest`:

```
py.test --version
This is pytest version 4.6.11, imported from /home/myhome/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc
```

But my current python setup (`python --version`) was `3.7.7.`. I had to run this instead:

```
python -m pytest --version
pytest 6.2.1
```

Similarly you can run `python -m pytest file_name.py` or for coverage `python -m pytest --cov=my_project tests/`.

I always recommend to check this especially when there are any issues and I think it's a good practice to run this with `-m` instead of using `pytest` directly as it may easily happen it points to different version than the one that should be used within your current python environment. (See similar explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install).)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my versions mismatched.

I changed the versions to

```
pytest="*"
pytest-cov="*"
```

and it started to work.