# Why is "-m" needed for "python -m pip install ..."?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I recently used pip to install the `requests` package in python 2.7, however in order to do so I had to use:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

instead of just:

```
python pip install requests
```

which gave me an error:

> can't open file 'pip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Why did I need to add the `-m`?

Comment: Are those the complete command you used? (I suspect not)  Did you have `python ` in front of each of these?

Comment: I did yes, the entire command was > python -m pip install requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between pip install and python -m pip install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`python -m pip` tells python to run with the `pip` module as the main module.

`python pip` isn't understood, because pip isn't a command line argument that python understands (i.e., `pip` is a module).

If the python scripts directory (`c:\python27\scripts` for python 2.7 on windows) is on your path, then you can just run `pip` (without `python` before it) and pass the same options you would pass to `python -m pip`.

So: you need to add `-m pip` so python knows what module to use as the main module.  `pip` is a standalone program installed in your python scripts directory, not an argument to python.

Comment: you can control the target directory of installation if you used python -m pip

Comment: how is this different from just doing `pip install <package name>`?

Comment: `python -m pip install ...` and `pip install ...` are the same if the python scripts directory is on your path.  On windows, you need to use `python -m pip install -U pip` to upgrade pip itself, because otherwise pip.exe (in the scripts directory) can't be replaced and the install will fail.