# What is the difference between 'pip install <package>' and 'python -m pip install <package>'?

Tags: python, pip

**In which circumstances would one use one approach over the other? Are there downsides to both approaches?**

I have seen both approaches, but I don't know, what the difference between both is and I can't seem to find an answer to that question. Are there differences in behaviour? Or is one just an evolved version of the other?

For example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7) both approaches are used among all the answers.

**Note:** There also seem to be a quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392499/why-is-m-needed-for-python-m-pip-install), but this question only deals with the necessity of providing `-m` when using `python -m pip install <package>`, but not with the differences between the two approaches above.

Comment: There's an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392499/why-is-m-needed-for-python-m-pip-install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pip install ...` invokes the `pip` executable which has to be on your path. `python -m pip ...` [invokes](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) the pip [application](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) that corresponds to this python installation (i.e. Python will use its normal import mechanism to resolve the `pip` package).

Usually these two approaches are the same, but think about what happens after `alias pip=echo`; the `python -m pip ...` approach is still going to work.

For example you can use the `python -m pip ...` approach if you're inside a virtual environment, but you want to install a package into another Python installation:

```
(somevenv) $ pip install ...   # installs into 'somevenv'
(somevenv) $ /path/to/othervenv/bin/python -m pip install ...  # installs into 'othervenv'
```

In the end, `python -m pip ...` is always going to use the 'correct' installation of Python, assuming that you intended to use whatever `python` points to.

If you want to [install a distribution from within a running script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12332975/3767239) then using the `python -m pip` approach is also the preferred way according to the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the Python's `Scripts` directory, and the Python main directory, i.e. for example the directories

```
c:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\
c:\Program Files\Python38\
```

already in your `PATH` variable (the first is for the `pip` executable, the second is for the `python` executable), then both

```
pip install [options] <package>
python -m pip install [options] <package>
```

*will execute the same code,* so it looks like there are totally equivalent. **But there is a one (and only one) exception** – if you want to **upgrade the pip itself**.

In this case **you have to launch `python`**, because in opposite case (launching `pip` directly), the **running** `pip` is not able to rewrite itself:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip    ;; correct, will upgrade
pip install --upgrade pip              ;; incorrect, will NOT upgrade
```