# How to generate text using GPT2 model with Huggingface transformers?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, gpt-2, large-language-model

I wanted to use **GPT2Tokenizer**, **AutoModelForCausalLM** for generating (rewriting) sample text. I have tried `transformers==4.10.0`, `transformers==4.30.2` and `--upgrade git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git`, however I get the error of `AttributeError: 'GPT2LMHeadModel' object has no attribute 'compute_transition_scores`.

My code is as follows:

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x = "sample Text" #df_toxic['text'].iloc[0]

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
inputs = tokenizer(x, return_tensors="pt")

# Example 1: Print the scores for each token generated with Greedy Search
outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=5, return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True)
transition_scores = model.compute_transition_scores(
    outputs.sequences, outputs.scores, normalize_logits=True
)
# input_length is the length of the input prompt for decoder-only models, like the GPT family, and 1 for
# encoder-decoder models, like BART or T5.
input_length = 1 if model.config.is_encoder_decoder else inputs.input_ids.shape[1]
generated_tokens = outputs.sequences[:, input_length:]
for tok, score in zip(generated_tokens[0], transition_scores[0]):
    # | token | token string | logits | probability
    print(f"| {tok:5d} | {tokenizer.decode(tok):8s} | {score.numpy():.3f} | {np.exp(score.numpy()):.2%}")
```

I got the error of:

```
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [21], line 3
      1 # Example 1: Print the scores for each token generated with Greedy Search
      2 outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=5, return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True)
----> 3 transition_scores = model.compute_transition_scores(
      4     outputs.sequences, outputs.scores, normalize_logits=True
      5 )
      6 # # input_length is the length of the input prompt for decoder-only models, like the GPT family, and 1 for
      7 # # encoder-decoder models, like BART or T5.
      8 # input_length = 1 if model.config.is_encoder_decoder else inputs.input_ids.shape[1]
   (...)
     11 #     # | token | token string | logits | probability
     12 #     print(f"| {tok:5d} | {tokenizer.decode(tok):8s} | {score.numpy():.3f} | {np.exp(score.numpy()):.2%}")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1207, in Module.__getattr__(self, name)
   1205     if name in modules:
   1206         return modules[name]
-> 1207 raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
   1208     type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'GPT2LMHeadModel' object has no attribute 'compute_transition_scores'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate text using `transformers` and GPT2 model, if you're not particular about modifying different generation features you can use the pipeline function, e.g.

```
from transformers import pipeline

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
generator("Hello world, continue... ")
```

[out]:

```
[{'generated_text': 'Hello world, continue... !! A group of two great people from Finland came to my office and brought me with them, and I got some beautiful drawings with the colours. I thought I gave it to the artist but that was not the case.'}]
```

---

If you have somehow have to use `GPT2Tokenizer` and `AutoModelForCausalLM` instead of using `pipeline`, you can try `AutoTokenizer` instead of `GPT2Tokenizer`, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id


x = "Hello world, ..."
inputs = tokenizer(x, return_tensors="pt")

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id


x = "Hello world, ..."
inputs = tokenizer(x, return_tensors="pt")

model_outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=5, return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True)

generated_tokens_ids = model_outputs.sequences[0]

tokenizer.decode(generated_tokens_ids)
```

[out]:

```
Hello world,...\n\nI'm sorry
```

---

To use the `compute_transition_scores` function implemented in https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/announcement-generation-get-probabilities-for-generated-output/30075/24

First make sure you really have the update version of transformers by doing:

```
import transformers
print(transformers.__version__)
```

If the version is after the feature have been implemented, this should give no error:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id

model.compute_transition_scores
```

[out]:

```
<bound method GenerationMixin.compute_transition_scores of GPT2LMHeadModel(...)
```

If you see the `AttributeError`,

```
AttributeError: 'GPT2LMHeadModel' object has no attribute 'compute_transition_scores'
```

most probably your current Python kernel (maybe inside Jupyter) isn't the right one that you have with your `pip`. If so, check your executable:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Then you should see something like:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

After that, instead of simple `pip install -U transformers` reuse that above python binary and do:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U transformers
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between "pip install" and "python -m pip install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install)
- [Why is "-m" needed for "python -m pip install ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392499/why-is-m-needed-for-python-m-pip-install)