# Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\...\.conda\envs\env_STAligner\python.exe "C:\Users\...\.conda\envs\env_STAligner\Scripts\pip-script.py" '

Tags: python-3.x, pip, path, environment, anaconda3

When I create a new virtual environment with anaconda use
`conda create -n env_STAligner python=3.8`
I cannot use pip inside this environment but all other environment including system env. The error I encountered is:
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users....conda\envs\env_STAligner\python.exe "C:\Users....conda\envs\env_STAligner\Scripts\pip-script.py" '
Some weeks ago, I updated the newest pip version and add `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts` to the system path(the installing guideline told me to do that). I think it maybe one of the reason why...
And my conda list is:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2023.05.30           haa95532_0
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
openssl                   3.0.10               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       23.2.1           py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.17               h1aa4202_0
setuptools                68.0.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.38.4           py38haa95532_0
```

So any usual method to add or upgrade pip actually did not help me. But when I type 'where pip'(yes, I use Windows11), just nothing out.

I tried delete this environment and create a new one but met the same question. Also 'conda install pip' and 'conda upgrade pip' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The environment you're trying to use might not be a registered python path. Try putting "python -m" in your pip command, like this:

```
python -m pip install pendulum
```

"pendulum" is just an example package, any valid package should work (pandas, polars, etc.). This post does a good job of explaining why:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409521/5834512