# How to pip install a local python package?

Tags: python, pip, python-import

**Question**

I installed a local package called `credentials` using

```
pip install -e c:\users\worker\src\clockwork\lib\credentials
```

But when I try to import the package from a sibling directory, it fails with an ImporError:

```
cd c:\users\worker\src\clockwork\bank
python -c "import credentials"
...
ImportError: No module named 'credentials'
```

Confusingly, the package `credentials` is listed as successfully installed as shown when I run `pip list`:

```
...
credentials (1.0.0, c:\users\worker\src\clockwork\lib\credentials)
...
```

How can I install my local package so that it can be imported?

**Background**

I am using Python 3.4 (32-bit). The package contains two files:

```
credentials\__init__.py
credentials\setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` file defines a single function. The `setup.py` file is short:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='credentials', version='1.0.0')
```

**Workaround**

I currently add the directory containing the package (`c:\users\worker\src\clockwork\lib`) to my `PATH` variable as a workaround. But my question is how to install the package properly so that I do not need to modify the `PATH`.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: It looks to me like your `setup.py` is *too* short.  See the example in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example) (and [another](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)).  You didn't specify any modules or packages to install.

Comment: @BrenBarn your comment is half the answer. The other half is to create a subdirectory for the package and leave setup.py in the parent directory. If you post it as an answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem centers on `setup.py`. It needs to declare a package:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='credentials', version='1.0.0', packages=['credentials'])
```

But this `setup.py` must be in the parent directory of the `credentials` package, so in the end, the directory structure is:

```
...\credentials\setup.py
...\credentials\credentials\__init__.py
```

With this change, the module is found after reinstalling the package.

This could also be caused by two Python installs (but wasn't in my case), and @Mr_and_Mrs_D gives an answer for that case.

Comment: Thank you!
That solved indeed my problem! 
One more question: are you supposed to put `requirements.txt`in `...\credentials` or `...\credentials\credentials`?

Comment: In `...\credentials`.

Answer (score 57):

Uninstall the python package then install it using:

```
python -m pip install -e c:\users\worker\src\clockwork\lib\credentials
```

What is probably happening is that you have multiple python installs and pip is run from one install while you are trying to use the package from another. See also:

- [What's the difference between pip install and python -m pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25749621/281545)
- https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#basic-usage