# Python - imports and folder structure

Tags: python, import

I have the following file structure:

```
command.py
simulations
  basis
    basis.py
  hamiltonian
    hamiltonian.py
```

where the names without extensions are folders.

- `command.py` is importing `basis.py` and `hamiltonian.py` like:

> from basis.basis import Basis
>
> from hamiltonian.hamiltonian import Hamiltonian

where `Basis` and `Hamiltonian` are two classes.

I can run `command.py` fine, all the imports are Okay.

- Now, I want to work with `hamiltonian.py` alone, but it needs to import `basis.py`.
- In order for `command.py` to work fine, the import in `hamiltonian.py` has to be `from basis.basis import Basis`
- In order for hamiltonian.py to run on its own, the import needs to be

  `os.chdir('..')`  
  `from basis.basis import Basis` 
   however this makes `command.py` not work anymore.

--

1) Can I somehow run the  `os.chdir('..')` only if `hamiltonian.py` is run on its own? Like with `if name == 'main'`?

2) Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: you need \_\_init__.py files in those directories that will act as modules (simulations I supose)
Then in commands you have.from simulations.whatever.whatever import whatever
And in hamiltonians from simulations.whatever.whatever import whatever

Comment: yes I have an init. The issue is that hamiltonian is used also by command as well

Comment: by the looks of it...this looks like a bad design for classes in first place!

Comment: @NoobEditor then could please tell me what a better method could be? basis.py and hamiltonian.py are producing npy arrays and pdfs which I am saving in the same folder. Which is why I wanted to put them in separate folders. So with this folder structure, what would be a better class design in your opinion?

Comment: Google something about repo structure and init files packages and modules. Not trying to be rude, but you Will thank me in a couple of months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can, but its not a good idea. It is better to avoid using `os.chdir`.

2) The fact that you need `os.chdir` suggests that you are trying to run it locally like:

```
python ./simulations/hamiltonian/hamiltonian.py
```

If this is the case, use:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python ./simulations/hamiltonian/hamiltonian.py
```

You will not run into this problem if you properly *install* the python package and your package has the proper `__init__.py` files as suggested by @E.Serra.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by properly install? THey are both scripts that I have written. My init is empty, it's just there so that the folder is seen as a python repository. What should the init have to be "proper"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494229/how-to-pip-install-a-local-python-package for installing local python package. Empty `__init__.py` files are fine; by "proper" I meant that you have them in all directories that are needed (i.e. in `simulations` as well as in `basis` and in `hamiltonian`)

Comment: I definitely have all the inits, because I can find all the imports, if I just use <code>chdir</code>. Why should I not use <code>os.chdir</code>?

Comment: What's the difference between importing my script and installing a local pacakge?

Comment: Also from what I can see PYTHONPATH is only used when running stuff from the terminal? I am indeed trying to run it locally, but always within spyder

Comment: Installing the package basically puts it to a known path. see  e.g. https://github.com/flatironinstitute/CaImAn/wiki/Setting-up-Python-and-getting-to-know-Spyder#the-pythonpath-variable . Also you can specify PYTHONPATH before running `spyder` please consult the same link.

Comment: OKay yes this worked very nicely with the PYTHONPATH! Thanks.

Comment: This is a one time sesión answer also do not overwrite pythonpath, append to it instead PYTHONPATH=PYTHONPATH:ADDITIONAL PYTHON PATH. This Will do the trick but it is not a good solución.