# pip Install Editable Package Produces ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, python-venv

Due to import issues, I've followed the steps shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/6221414) to install my Python project as an editable `pip` package. Basically this entails running `pip install -e .` from my project root directory. The name of the project is 'myproject', with the `setup.py` configured as such:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

The project structure is like so:

```
.
├── myproject
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_one.py
├── setup.py
└── env
    └── ...
```

With the `venv` activated, I get the following output:

```
(env) [root@localhost /]$ python -V
Python 3.6.3

(env) [root@localhost /]$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /myproject/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

However, when running an interpreted session I experience the following:

```
(env) [root@localhost /]$ python
>>> import myproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
>>> from myproject.core import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```

Starting up another interpreted session and running the `setuptools` stuff myself results in:

```
(env) [root@localhost /]$ python
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages()
>>> ['core', 'tests']
```

I've also tried other methods of installing it, including:

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

And still get the same problems. Finally, I can do the following:

```
(env) [root@localhost /] pip list installed | grep myproject
myproject (1.0, /myproject)
```

**UPDATE**: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42541684/6221414) and as mentioned by @Fletchy1995 below, changing the directory structure so that it is instead like:

```
.
├── setup.py
├── myproject
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_one.py
├── __init__.py
└── env
    └── ...
```

And modifying `setup.py` to look like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=['myproject'])
```

along with running `pip install -e .` from the top level directory seems to have fixed the problem. But **in the previous case**, even though the packages loaded include all sub-packages of 'myproject', why can I still not do something like:

```
(env) [root@localhost /]$ python
>>> from myproject.core import *
```

as 'myproject' is listed in `pip`?

Comment: ```(env) $ python``` are you in a Anaconda environment (or similar) or are you just stating the directory you are currently in?  If its a directory, perhaps try backing out one directory and trying again.

Comment: That is just to show the commands are being executed from the shell and with the `venv` activated. I've tried it from the directory containing `setup.py` as well as the directory above it. Also, I've edited the question to make my first statement more apparent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: I've been facing similar issues with [frappe](https://github.com/frappe/frappe) as well, which installs all its apps in editable mode. However, the problem exists only in macOS currently. any distro of Linux works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it appears you are missing __init__.py in your myproject subdirectory. Python does not consider a directory to be a package/subpackage unless it contains __init__.py.

Answer (score -1):

It may work if you modify the `setup.py` to

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=find_packages(where='myproject'))
```

Then, you can then run `pip install -e` from the root directory to install the package in editable mode.