# pip cannot import Cython but python setup.py install can

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools

I am writing a Cython module. I have Cython installed. The start of my `setup.py` file is as follows:

```py
import os
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
from typing import Callable

from setuptools import setup, Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
```

When I run `pip install .`, I end up with the following error:

```py
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

However, if I run `python setup.py install`, everything works as expected.

I have ran `pip install Cython --upgrade`.

Python version: 3.7.10

Cython version: 0.29.23

pip version: 21.0.1

I am certain that more information will be needed, but not sure what I should provide.

Edit:

Python path: `/Users/petioptrv/miniconda3/envs/ib-insync-sim-test/bin/python`

pip path: `/Users/petioptrv/miniconda3/envs/ib-insync-sim-test/bin/pip`

As evident by the path, I use conda to manage my environment.

Comment: Does the python version displayed by `pip --version` match?

Comment: This is a weird one. What are the paths to the binaries (e.g. `which pip`, `which python`)? What kind of system are you on (Windows, Mac, Linux)? Do you use additional software to manage environments (`pyenv`, `conda`)?

Comment: Use python -m pip install, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25749621/5769463

Comment: @ead unfortunately, did not solve the problem

Comment: use `python3 -m pip install` ? if you have python2 installed, don't forget the **3** when you want python3

Comment: I have the exact same issue, googling didn't help me either. Did you come by any solution by any chance @PetioPetrov ?

Comment: Update, I have found something that works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072011/getting-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-third-party-modules-in-setup-p . Hope this will help someone.