# Python and pip installation on Mac don't show version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

On Mac OS.

Downloaded the `Python` from their website.

`Python -V` return `Python 2.7.16`, and
`python3 -V` return `Python 3.9.4`

Installed `pip` with : `python3 get-pip.py`, got `Successfully installed pip-21.0.1`

But when I run `pip -V`
I get `File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 1.... SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

After reading here a lot, i could not understand (in simple words for dumbs) :

1. How could you "alias" or update python to show/run in version 3+ ?
2. Why I can't get the `pip` version **if it's installed** ?

Comment: Try pip --version

Comment: You might need to use `pip3` given that you have two different python versions.

Comment: --version Same exact error. syntax error that show many paths to files, something like :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point

Comment: @astrochun that's strange because i just downloaded both - the most updated versions. Mac use python 2 and i understand you cant touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pip as a module instead

```sh
% python3 -m pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: thank you, this return "pip 21.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)" , can you explain in simple words what does it means and what did we do ?

Comment: anytime ; this is probably a better explanation than I can give here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install

Comment: thank you, but your answer was not installing anything? and i installed pip with python3 get-pip.py, which is non of the options in the question you linked? very confused.

Comment: investigating a little, it comes from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)'s Python package which bundles it `brew ls --verbose python@3.9 | grep -i pip` ; it can be installed as `brew install python@3.9`

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who's interested , what i had to do is to

1. CD the project on terminal
2. run `python3 -m venv env` (this create virtual environment of python3 inside project)
3. run `source env/bin/activate` activate it.
4. now `pip --version` or `python --version` will return the right results.

From my basic knowledge i understand that the mac is using python2 which we don't want to interrupt, so we install python3 and create a 'virtual environment' for it inside our project folder, once its in, we can install all other things.

to deactivate (stop the virtual env) we run `deactivate`