# Although installed pyg_lib successfully, getting error while importing

Tags: python, importerror

I have successfully installed `pyg_lib` on my Mac (intel cpu) with anaconda Jupyter notebook. So, when I run this code:

`pip install pyg_lib`

it returns:

`Requirement already satisfied: pyg_lib in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.2.0+pt20)`
`Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.`

But when I want to import the package using `import pyg_lib`, it raises the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libpyg.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python'
  Referenced from: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libpyg.so'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file)
```

I looked everywhere for a solution to the problem, but nothing worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.

Python: 3.11

torch: 2.0.0+cpu

I also installed pyg_lib with the suggested command (i.e. `pip install pyg_lib -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.0.0+cpu.html`)

Comment: your pip seems to report that its running as python 3.8 while other paths point to python 3.10.

Comment: @rasjani How can I fix that? Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your package binaries are in

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

but it is not in path, as the system tried:

```
tried: '/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python'(no such file),
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file),
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file)
```

Thus, pip is using other version of Python as the python executable.

I suggest you to install the package with:

```
python -m pip install pyg_lib
```

It will use the same version as executable.

Reference: [What's the difference between "pip install" and "python -m pip install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749621/whats-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-python-m-pip-install)

EDIT:

You may want to try also:

```
python -m pip install pyg_lib -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.0.0+cpu.html
```

Comment: python -mpip install pyg_lib you meant ?

Comment: Yes! I wrote it on the wrong way. I will edit the post