# Using pip to install iPython Notebook

Tags: pip, ipython, jupyter

Edit:

According to the pip website ([https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)), I should already have pip installed with my Python version 2.9.7, but I assumed that I don't because of the error message.

I then attempted to install pip by downloading get-pip.py. It was successful but I got the messages:

```
Found existing installation: pip 1.3.1
Uninstalling pip-1.3.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip-1.3.1
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1 wheel-0.29.0
```

So it seems I **did** have a version of pip, so I'm not sure why I was getting the error message described in my original post.

But when I tried to then pip install jupyter, I just get:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

again. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

---

I need to install iPython Notebook. I already have Python (version 2.7.9) installed on my Macbook, running OS X (version 10.7.5).

After some initial investigation, I saw somebody say that I could just run:

```
pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

When I did this however, I got:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So do I have to install pip first? And then use pip to install the Notebook? I'm out of my depth and a little confused!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to install pip. Info is here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Note that the IPython Notebook has been renamed the Jupyter Notebook. You can still [install it](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#existing-python-new-jupyter) with pip: `pip install jupyter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so my problem was that pip was installed, but in a location that was not included in my $PATH variable.

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found) is relevant.