# pip3: command not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, homebrew

I want to install TensorFlow following these instructions: https://web.archive.org/web/20170627102751/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation

But when I try this code on terminal, it returns an error.

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

So I installed Homebrew and tried to uninstall and reinstall python3-pip, but didn't work.

```
MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ brew uninstall python3-pip
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python3-pip

MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ brew install python3-pip
Error: No available formula with the name "python3-pip" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

What should I do for getting pip3?
My OS is macOS High Sierra, and I have Python 3.6.2 already installed.

EDIT: I tried

```
python3 -m pip
```

and what's returned was this:

```
The directory '/Users/makotomiyazaki/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its 
parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has 
been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that 
directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/makotomiyazaki/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent 
directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been 
disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If 
executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help 
install")
```

I also tried which pip3, but just I don't know if it worked...

```
MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ sudo which pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
/usr/bin/install
```

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip` work? You should be installing packages into a venv anyway, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found)

Comment: Did you try `which pip3`?  I have both python2 and python3 installed and since I am too lazy to set up aliases I will have to do the entire path.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried both but it doesn't seem to have worked...

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You would need to install pip3.

On Linux, run first `sudo apt update`. Then the command would be: `sudo apt install python3-pip`
On Mac, using brew, first `brew install python3`
Then `brew postinstall python3`

Try calling `pip3 -V` to see if it worked.

Comment: This gives me an error `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal': Permission denied`
I will keep on investigating

Comment: @AmauryLiet can you specify which command gave you that error?

Comment: I ran `brew postinstall python3`

I tried `brew uninstall python3`
which wasn't enough, but this did the trick:
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.6`

Comment: `brew postinstall python3` was what I needed

Comment: No package python3-pip available.

Comment: for me brew postinstall python3 says Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully, You can try again using `brew postinstall python3`

Comment: So when I updated brew upgrade python3 and then when ran `brew postinstall python3` worked for me

Comment: i get command not found after installing an app with pip3

Answer (score 25):

I had this issue and I fixed it using the following steps
You need to completely uninstall python3-pip using:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip
```

Then resintall the package with:

```
 sudo apt install python3-pip
```

To confirm that everything works, run:

```
 pip3 -V
```

After this you can now use pip3 to manage any python package of your interest. Eg

```
pip3 install NumPy
```

Comment: This issue appeared for me after reinstall mysql server.  The above, solved it.

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped. I had same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the whole path/directory eg. (for windows) `C:\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip3.exe install mypackage`. This worked well for me when I had trouble with pip.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! But I'm not sure which directory I should write. I am relatively new to my Mac also...

Answer (score 2):

its possible if you already have a python installed (pip) you could do a upgrade on mac by

```
brew upgrade python
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if other methods do not work:

1. brew install python3
2. brew link --overwrite python
3. brew postinstall python3

Answer (score 1):

In my case, although python3-pip was already installed, it didn't recognize pip3. After reinstalling with

`sudo yum reinstall python3-pip`

it worked fine and recognized pip3 commands.

Answer (score 0):

After `yum install python3-pip`, check the name of the installed binary. e.g.

```
ll /usr/bin/pip*
```

On my CentOS 7, it is named as `pip-3` instead of `pip3`.