# pip command not found after installed it

Tags: python, macos, pip, moviepy

I'm stuck with an issue. I have a Python script that I would like to run on my OSX but seems that I crossed on many issues.

To run the script I should have both Python and Moviepy installed.

To install Moviepy I used this command:

```
sudo pip install moviepy
```

The response was:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

So I tried to install pip, with the command:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And got this answer:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Processing pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

I tried to run again the

```
sudo pip install moviepy
```

but I still got that issue. What I should do?

**UPDATE:**

> not sure on OSX, but can u try pip3 – Rehan Azher 23 mins ago

```
sudo pip3 install moviepy
Password:
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

> It seems that pip is not in your path, but as long as Python can find it: sudo python -m pip install moviepy should do it. Check your $PATH env. variable, tho. – zwer 14 mins ago

```
sudo python -m pip install moviepy
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

**UPDATE2**

> A good option for you is to consider installing pip using one of OSX's
>   sources, like the apt program in Debian-based distributions, rather
>   than easy_install. – Shiva 4 hours ago

```
sudo apt install moviepy
Password:
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

> No idea why everyone keeps getting stuck on this. You have a
>   fundamental decision to make when using Python. You either run Python
>   2.7 that Apple ships and which is ancient and doesn't have pip or you use homebrew and install Python3 and pip3 and put /usr/local/bin at
>   the start of your PATH. But don't try a mixture of the two. – Mark
>   Setchell 3 hours ago

Tried to install homebrew but it cannot find the package moviepy that I am looking for.

Comment: not sure on OSX, but can u try pip3

Comment: It seems that `pip` is not in your path, but as long as Python can find it: `sudo python -m pip install moviepy` should do it. Check your `$PATH` env. variable, tho.

Comment: Is this default OSX Python or has it been installed via e.g. Homebrew?

Comment: A good option for you is to consider installing `pip` using one of OSX's sources, like the `apt` program in Debian-based distributions, rather than `easy_install`.

Comment: No idea why everyone keeps getting stuck on this. You have a fundamental decision to make when using Python. You either run Python 2.7 that Apple ships and which is ancient and doesn't have `pip` or you use **homebrew** and install Python3 and `pip3` and put `/usr/local/bin` at the start of your PATH. But don't try a mixture of the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found)

Answer (score 6):

Try with this:

```
pip3 install package-name
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a mess. Today, your best option is to leave the ageing, OS-provided version of Python (all the stuff in `/Library/Python` and similar) alone and start fresh.

It looks like you've already done this (since you have an executable at `/usr/bin/python`) but if not, the easiest way to get Python 2 is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Install Homebrew using the instructions on the website and then use it to install Python:

```
brew install python@2
```

Python 2.7.9+ comes with `pip` already, but if you've ended up with an older version then use python itself and `get-pip.py` to install pip (instead of `easy_install`, which is deprecated):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Note that `get-pip.py` includes a copy of `pip` in order to install `pip` effectively. Yes, things are that bad.

Finally, note that Python 2 will be end of life in less than 6 months. If you have the luxury, consider skipping straight to Python 3. Then it's as easy as:

```
brew install python
```

because `pip3` comes with `python3` since version 3.4. Homebrew manages to handle the installation of both Python 2 and Python 3 without conflict.

Note this procedure is different on every operating system and every month or two. But at least it should get you going for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to python shell and type `import pip`? If that works, then it means the `pip` package is installed, but there is no command-line script/program available.

In my computer, the command-line `pip` program is actually a python script in itself, and is located in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is in my `PATH`. Below are the contents of my `pip` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

This is a dirty trick. What you could do is to create a new file called `pip` in your `/usr/local/bin/` directory (or similar for OSX) and copy the above lines into it.

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/pip # create a new empty file called "pip"
# ... open the file in your favorite editor, copy the above contents and save the file
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pip # make it executable
```

The first line in the file (`#!/usr/bin/python`), called "Shebang", points to the program that should execute this file when you run it on your command-line. You should put the path to the python program in your computer over there.