# Python Modules installing properly but dont exist in editors

Tags: python

I want to start with I am new to the python language and am learning on my own. My issue is that I am installing the modules that I'm trying to use. The installs are successful but do not exist when I try to import them. I am using Visual Studio Code, Python 3.6, and Anaconda on Windows 10.

I am trying to use pyttsx3, SpeechRecognition and pocketsphinx.

```
    $pip list
```

This gives me a very large list but does not contain either of my installed modules.

```
    $python -m pip list
```

Gives me smaller output with them.

```
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
beautifulsoup4    4.6.0
bs4               0.0.1
certifi           2018.4.16
chardet           3.0.4
click             6.7
gTTS              2.0.0
gTTS-token        1.1.1
idna              2.6
pip               10.0.1
pocketsphinx      0.1.3 #Here
pypiwin32         223
pyttsx            1.1
pyttsx3           2.7 #Here
pywin32           223
requests          2.18.4
setuptools        39.1.0
six               1.11.0
SpeechRecognition 3.8.1 #Here
urllib3           1.22
wheel             0.31.0
```

I know their installed but when I try to use any of the imports.

```
$python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyttsx3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

I am fine with this being something small on my part due to my lack of knowledge with this language, but I have done a full days worth of research trying to solve this myself.

Edit:

```
$pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from C:\Users\Keiro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: run `pip show pyttsx3`. Where did it install that package? In python, run `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Do you see that path there? It's probably looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I might be completly wrong here, but you want to use `python3`, right? Shouldn't you use `pip3`? Could it be that you installed the modules for python2?

Comment: Can you run `Get-Command python` and `Get-Command pip` in powershell?

Comment: pyttsx is not in conda

Comment: @MaxNoe `Get-Command python` and `Get-Command pip` are not recognized `pip3` is also not recognized

Comment: And if you add .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two versions of `pip` perhaps two different installations of python as well. One with Anaconda and other one by main site.

Stick to one version and if you install in that use that environment in Visual Studio(Or VS Code)

You have installed those in anaconda which the standard installtion of Python wont recognize..

Open Python prompt from `Anaconda Navigator` >> Choose the environment (Select base for default) >> Open with Terminal [Or Open with Python]

```
>>python
>>import pyttsx3
```

In Visual Studio code set [the same environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Ctrl+Shift+P >> Select Python interpreter

Choose the anaconda location.

Volla. Now it should work

Comment: This worked, thank you. I didn't fully understand how installing modules worked, I do now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer in an old forum.

Write "pip3" instead of "pip".
So the code is:

pip3 install pyttsx3

(Source: [bash: pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found))