# VS Code Doesn't recognize Anaconda pkgs/libs even when in correct env

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, anaconda

I've installed a few different libraries using Anaconda but whenever I try launching in VS Code it doesn't recognize the libraries even when running through the Conda environment.

[image: Anaconda Navigator]

Then say I click the Jupyter Launch button and create a new .py file & I can import Numpy all good and well [image]

But I want to launch in VS Code say, so I launch from the Navigator and I'm getting an error?[image]

Correct env too [image]

Comment: You got invalid syntax error. Missing comma before `dtype`.

Comment: @9dogs sorry yes, I reuploaded the "No module" error now

Comment: You can try selecting different interpreter. In VSCode press `CTRL+SHIFT+p`, command palette will open. Type 'select interpreter' and press ENTER. Then choose one with `Anaconda` with it (or your virtualenv name with `numpy` installed).

Comment: @9dogs I tried that got a 'pyhton.setinterpreter' error; uninstalled VS Code and reinstalled it - works but still getting same ImportError

Comment: I reinstalled everything & installed anaconda with the ADD TO PATH setting but still not working

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178109/python-modules-installing-properly-but-dont-exist-in-editors/50178345#50178345) I believe it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Anaconda packages and libraries in your Linux subsystem on Windows. Your integrated terminal is a Bash shell on Windows 10, which does not have any installed package and library for your code.

Try `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and `pip install numpy` or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and `pip3 install numpy` on integrated terminal in vscode.

If this solves your module error for numpy, try the following lines to install conda in your Linux subsystem, or you can just use pip to manage your python packages and libraries.

```
curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

This will give the following output and type yes to this:

```
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location
to PATH in your /home/[username]/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
```

Then, source your `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, you can use command `conda` to install packages. Try to install packages and libraries you want with the following command:

```
conda install [package name]
```

Or you can check what is installed on your conda with the following command:

```
conda list
```

Comment: great, but I'm getting errors when trying to [pip install packages](https://imgur.com/oBITBqD)

Comment: try `python3 test.py`. Because you installed your package with pip3, numpy package is installed for python3.

Comment: Ideal, I'm trying to Install conda to the linux subsystem now but it won't let me install to .bashrc only to `/home/andre/Anaconda3` that should  be fine right?

Comment: Of course! Your Anaconda3 should be installed in /home/andre/Anaconda3 and the installer will prepend that location to PATH in your .bashrc. .bashrc and `source ~/.bashrc` let you use conda in the terminal.

Comment: This worked well, but its still [not recognizing the conda packages](https://imgur.com/loWzGBe) Should I just forget about conda entirely and keep installing via pip3?

Comment: You should install packages via conda or pip3, because Linux subsystem does not share any packages from your windows machine.