# Pip command not found when installing on OSX using get-pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

It appears as though pip is installing fine (it says it "Successfully installed pip-19.1.1"), but I cannot located pip on my computer afterwards.  I'm running OSX 10.14.4.

I haven't used Python recently on my Mac, and I recently upgraded to Python3 for a project, which requires me to use pip as well.  I had pip already installed and working, but it kept trying to use Python 2.7, so I decided to uninstall and reinstall pip with the new version of Python.  I've gone through a few tutorials to try and install pip.  Most recently, I've tried the method recommended here: https://ahmadawais.com/install-pip-macos-os-x-python/, which has me run:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

This appears to work just fine:

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 706kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.1.1
Successfully installed pip-19.1.1
```

However, attempting to use pip after this results in "command not found".  I realize that the likely issue is that it's just not in my PATH, but I don't know how to locate it to add it to my path.

Please let me know if there's anything else that would be useful to diagnosing this.  I'm pretty new to working with these tools, so I might just be missing something obvious.

Comment: how about `python3 -m pip list` or `python -m pip list` ?

Comment: It should be at `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Answer (score 0):

You can either try:

```
pip3 install package-name
```

or you can add the `locate` the pip, and add if not already added into your path:

```
locate pip3

/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3.6
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3.7
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pip3
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pip3.6
/usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider/package/pip3.rb
```

Then select the right one for your use. Generally for the fresh install (python 3), you should do (see [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/) post):

```
pip3 install package-name
```

You can check the version using:

```
pip3 --version
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found) question if you have further issues.