# Pip says 'pip install --upgrade pip' but 'pip: command not found'

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

**My environment:**

- macOS 10.14.6
- Python 2.7.10
- Python 3.6.5
- pip  10.0.1

**My situation:**

I am trying to use OpenCV.
When I write this command

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

and then pip say this.

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
>
> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
>
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

So I try this

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then

> -bash: pip: command not found

I also did this

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

and then

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (10.0.1)

**What I tried**

1: Uninstall pip

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

2: Uninstall Homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

3: Reinstall Homebrew and the packages

4: Downgrade Python 3.7 to Python 3.6 to install OpenCV.

Comment: Try `pip3 install --upgrade pip` since that's the version you want to upgrade.

Comment: I also tried what you pointed out. But it went wrong like below.


pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50508580/4518341) for Mac OS.

Comment: Also the original question was already asked here: [bash: pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9780717/4518341), and your solution is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46725427/4518341)

Comment: documentation for [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)