# Can't Install prttsx3 in Terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I'm starting to learn python, I'm using python 3.8.1 and try to install this:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say("Testing")

engine.runAndWait()
```

but when I input `pip install pyttsx3` in terminal, it's like this

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I'm using MacOs Catalina 10.15.5

Thanks,

Comment: This requires an installation of `pip` on the MacOS system before installing the `prttsx3` module.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Use setuptools to install `pip`:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

(I know the above part of my answer is redundant with klobucar's, but I can't add comments yet), so here's an answer with a solution to `sudo: easy_install: command not found` on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Also, for python3, use `easy_install3` and `python3-setuptools`.

## from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found)